# How to forbid some enum value in enum type to XML representation mapping?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb, wsdl

I use `@XmlEnum` and `@XmlEnumValue` for mapping enum to XML representation (WSDL file). I need to omit one of the enumeration values. So it won't be a part of the WSDL file.

I need to omit enum value NONE. Tried this but doesn't work.

```
@XmlEnum
public enum Title { 
   @XmlEnumValue("mrs") MRS,
   @XmlEnumValue("mrs") MR,
   NONE;
   ..
}
```

This is the generated WSDL file.

```
<xs:simpleType name="title">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="mrs"/>    
    <xs:enumeration value="mr"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="NONE"/> <!-- I need to get rid of this enum value -->
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: If `NONE` isn't a valid value why model it? Perhaps you could use `null` to represent no title value?

Comment: That's just an example. You can assume another enumeration like "@XmlEnumValue("cat") CAT, @XmlEnumValue("dog") DOG, OTHER;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use an `XmlAdapter` for this.  Have it convert between your enum and an enum with the desired items.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class TitleAdapter extends XmlAdapter<TitleAdapter.AdaptedTitle, Title>{

    @XmlType(name="title")
    public enum AdaptedTitle {
        @XmlEnumValue("mrs") MRS,
        @XmlEnumValue("mrs") MR
    }

    @Override
    public Title unmarshal(AdaptedTitle v) throws Exception {
        switch(v) {
        case MRS:
            return Title.MRS;
        case MR:
            return Title.MR;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedTitle marshal(Title v) throws Exception {
        switch(v) {
        case MRS:
            return AdaptedTitle.MRS;
        case MR:
            return AdaptedTitle.MR;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then change your `Title` enum to:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TitleAdapter.class)
public enum Title { 
   MRS,
   MR,
   NONE;
}
```